# Application of derivatives: Profit analysis

Tags: functions, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

The sales revenue (in dollars) that a manufacturer receives for selling x units of a certain product
can be approximated by the function

```
R(x) = 900 loge(1 + x/300)
```

Further, each unit costs the manufacturer one dollar to produce, and the initial cost of adjusting
his machinery for production is $200, so that the total cost of production (in dollars) of x units
is C(x) = 200 + x.

Write down the profit, P(x) dollars, obtained by the production and sale of x units and hence
find the number of units which should be produced and sold for maximum profit. Calculate the
resulting maximum profit.

I get that the P(x) is R(X) - C(x) = 900 loge (1 + x/300 ) − 200 − x

How do I differentiate it further?

Comment: That's a pretty standard function...what about it do you find hard to differentiate?

Comment: It gives 3loge -1. How do I maximize it without x.

Comment: that is not the correct derivative, and the function you wrote is obviously not linear.  What is the derivative of $\ln (1+x)$?

Comment: Should say, it is hard to read what you wrote.  I assume that you meant to write $R(x)=900\ln \left(1+\frac x{300}\right)$.  If you meant something else, you should clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the chain rule and recall $(\ln x)’=\frac 1x$: $$P’(x)= 900\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{300}} \cdot\frac{1}{300} -0-1 $$ Setting this equal to zero you’ll get $x=600$, which you can check by the second derivative test to correspond to a maximum.